# Save original value of C++ preprocessor macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to save the original textual value of a macro so that I can then redefine the macro and still refer to the original value. My use case involves a macro to a macro, so that the value I am trying to save is still itself a macro. I have a small example of attempts in an online interpreter, which I am copying the code from here. I am aware that other SO questions discuss similar ideas but I have not found anything that covers my use case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(X) (#X)

#define GLOBAL_INT (3)

// I AM TRYING TO SAVE THE TEXTUAL MACRO CONTENT "GLOBAL_INT" (WITHOUT THE QUOTES)
//  IN ANOTHER MACRO SO THAT I CAN UNDEFINE GIM AND STILL REFER TO GLOBAL_INT

#define GIM (GLOBAL_INT)

#define GIM_SAVE (GIM)
#define GIM_SAVE_STR (STR(GIM))
#define STR_GIM_SAVE (STR(GIM_SAVE))
const char *strGimSave = STR(GIM_SAVE);
const char *gimSaveStr = GIM_SAVE_STR;
const char *strGimSaveM = STR_GIM_SAVE;
const char *gimStr = STR(GIM);

#undef GIM

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("strGimSave=%s\n", strGimSave);
    printf("gimSaveStr=%s\n", gimSaveStr);
    printf("strGimSaveM=%s\n", strGimSaveM);
    printf("gimStr=%s\n", gimStr);

    const char *gim_save = STR(GIM_SAVE);
    const char *gim_save_str = GIM_SAVE_STR;
    const char *str_gim_save = STR_GIM_SAVE;
    printf("\ngim_save=%s\n", gim_save);
    printf("gim_save_str=%s\n", gim_save_str);
    printf("str_gim_save=%s\n", str_gim_save);

    return 0;
}
```

[Same code in online interpreter](http://ideone.com/A6yI96)

Edit: I am trying to output "GLOBAL_INT" in the above code. The above code outputs:

```
strGimSave=GIM_SAVE
gimSaveStr=GIM
strGimSaveM=GIM_SAVE
gimStr=GIM

gim_save=GIM_SAVE
gim_save_str=GIM
str_gim_save=GIM_SAVE
```

Comment: Perhaps `BOOST_PP_SLOT`? It only works with integer data AFAICR, though.

Comment: This is tagged C++, so unless you are tied to compile time semantics of macros, why not build a class that stores value histories (also use `std::string`, iostreams, etc.)?

Comment: @crashmstr I am tied to compile time semantics of macros. Also the code I pasted is attempting to save value histories but I find that I am still unable to save the intended value.

Comment: @crashmstr Also, as far as I understand, saving the value in an actual  variable is diagnostic only for my purpose. The only way I can save the textual content of a macro is as a string, and there is no way that I know of to inject that string content back into a preprocessor macro that can be called later.

Comment: Some compilers allow for pragmas that can push and pop macros/defines.

Comment: @cppguy I have not found a way to use that to achieve my goal. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I thnik you should add an extra level of indirection to your stringifier (The `STR()` macro), to expand the macro argumment properly. Else the token stringfied is the argumment, not the argumment expanded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **not possible**. C/C++ preprocessor expands macros on evaluation only. There is no way to tell it to define macro to expanded result of another.

That said, the first part of your sample would actually do what you want if you used correct definition of STR:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// HERE, extra level of indirection
#define STR2(X) (#X)
#define STR(X) STR2(X)

#define GLOBAL_INT (3)

#define GIM (GLOBAL_INT)

#define GIM_SAVE (GIM)
#define GIM_SAVE_STR (STR(GIM))
#define STR_GIM_SAVE (STR(GIM_SAVE))
const char *strGimSave = STR(GIM_SAVE);
const char *gimSaveStr = GIM_SAVE_STR;
const char *strGimSaveM = STR_GIM_SAVE;
const char *gimStr = STR(GIM);

#undef GIM

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("strGimSave=%s\n", strGimSave);
    printf("gimSaveStr=%s\n", gimSaveStr);
    printf("strGimSaveM=%s\n", strGimSaveM);
    printf("gimStr=%s\n", gimStr);

    const char *gim_save = STR(GIM_SAVE);
    const char *gim_save_str = GIM_SAVE_STR;
    const char *str_gim_save = STR_GIM_SAVE;
    printf("\ngim_save=%s\n", gim_save);
    printf("gim_save_str=%s\n", gim_save_str);
    printf("str_gim_save=%s\n", str_gim_save);

    return 0;
}
```

Now produces

```
strGimSave=(((3)))
gimSaveStr=((3))
strGimSaveM=(((3)))
gimStr=((3))

gim_save=(GIM)
gim_save_str=GIM
str_gim_save=(GIM)
```

(See [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7f9ed58003c9761))

As you see once you `#undef GIM` the macros stop expanding to "3", but the string constants created while GIM was defined retain the value. With all the parenthesis that you've put into those macros.

Comment: I am still convinced that it is somehow possible, given the information here http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-cpp-en-4/macro-pitfalls.html 
here
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html 
and here
https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms 
perhaps using unbalanced nesting, tricks of recursion, etc.

Comment: @taz: No, it isn't. The right hand side of macro definition undergoes absolutely no expansion and macro expansion can't produce new `#define` directive. Without either of those there is no way to define macro `A` that would include _value_ of macro `B` even after you undefine `B`. You have to expand the macro to C/C++ code while all macros it depends on are still defined. Of course there is a lot that can be declared in C++ at one place and used much later.

Comment: @JanHudec you might want to check out Boost's completely standard-compliant way to define one macro to the expanded result of another: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/headers/slot/slot.html ;) (only works with integers, but it absolutely does work, and it's very clever)

Answer (score 2):

When applying preprocessor operators to macro argumments, you should add an extra level of indirection (Another macro) just to expand the macro argumments properly. Consider this example using the token concatenation operator (`##`):

```
#define TOKEN_CAT_IMPL(x,y) x##x
#define TOKEN_CAT(x,y) TOKEN_CAT_IMPL(x,y) // <--- Here x and y are expanded before passed
```

Now you could use it for whatever you like:

```
#define FOO_IDENTIFIER( id ) TOKEN_CAT( foo_ , id );
#define ID hello

int FOO_IDENTIFIER( ID ) = 0; // int foo_hello = 0;
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2fb202866a23706) is a running example.

#### EDIT:

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e931d1c2c2367a3) is your code working by applying the solution explained here. Note how the second outputs are `GIM`, since that macro was undefined and `GIM` was treated as a token only.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't see tokenpaste used in the question anywhere and I don't see you save expanded value of the macro (as the question asks for) anywhere either.

Comment: @JanHudec the expanding issue applies exactly in the `##` operator. Was just an example of the problem and how to solve it. Also the saving is done, because (If I'm not wrong) the problem was only about not expanding the macro args properly. Thats why my example includes an `ID` macro and a `FOO_IDENTIFIER(ID)`. Note how the macro is expanded and returns `foo_hello` instead of `foo_ID`

Comment: While the problem does manifest in the first part of the sample, it does not appear to be the main point of the question. Or it might be, but you need to use the code from the question to demonstrate it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this example to my example. I see that the macro is expanding to `foo_hello` instead of `foo_ID` but I do not have knowledge of 'hello'. If I could set the original value of the macro I am trying to save this would be easier. The macro actually ultimately expands to an external function, which I am trying to call.

Comment: @taz note the `#define ID hello`, equivalent to your `#define GIM (GLOBAL_INT)`. Also see the second link, contains your code fixed and running.

Comment: I'm trying to output 'GLOBAL_INT', not 'GIM'.

Comment: `TOKEN_CAT_IMPL(x,y)` implementation does **not** paste `x` and `y`.